# Extract zip with progress bar in PHP or RUBY

Tags: php, ruby, zip, progress-bar, extract

is there a way to call an ajax function that calls a php that extract a file and send progress via httpresponse so i can make a progress bar?

I know php is not a multithreading language so i'm learning ruby and i've seem some extract zip examples but have no idea about how can i know the progress of the file, maybe a new thread???

So any solution or idea either php or ruby is really welcome.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby ProgressBar gem and `net/http` to do this.

Here is the demo code:

```rb
url_base = ''   
url_path = ''     
@counter = 0  

Net::HTTP.start(url_base) do |http|  
  response = http.request_head(URI.escape(url_path))  
  puts (response['content-length'].to_i/(1024*1024)).to_s <<  'M'  
  pbar = ProgressBar.new("file name:", response['content-length'].to_i)  
  File.open("test.file", 'w') {|f|
    http.get(URI.escape(url_path)) do |str|  
    f.write str  
    @counter += str.length  
    pbar.set(@counter)  
 end  
}  
end  
pbar.finish  
puts "Done."
```